# OSX El Capitan only loads HTTPS pages

Tags: http, https, osx-elcapitan

I'm on Wifi in a coffee shops and non of my browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari) load any web pages that are not `HTTPS`. All `HTTPS` enabled pages load fine, but all of `HTTP` only pages result in a timeout. Where should I start looking?

Comment: There might be some rules in the wifi router @ the coffee shop. If you have some other device with you (phone), you may try opening a non HTTPS site on the same wifi network.

Comment: Doesn't work with my phone (Android) either :(

Comment: @SubratPattnaik I think it has more to do withO OSX El Capitan.